# How does xgboost model know which one is pos the other is neg? sklearn default 1 is pos 0 is neg?

Tags: python, parameters, scikit-learn, label, xgboost

I want to tune the xgboost scale_pos_weight parameter, this parameter is neg/pos, but how model know which label is neg or pos?

Assuming 1 is pos 0 is neg? But how about the label are not 1 or 0, the label is string such as: 'good' & 'normal'. Do I need to transform to 1 & 0 or '1' & '0'?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Some frameworks count labels, and treat the more common label as "neg" (background noise) and the less common label as "pos" (signal). Don't know for sure if XGBoost is doing it (also, this behaviour could be XGBoost version dependent).